# How should I install rope lights across a stair?

Tags: lighting, safety, light, walkway

I'm using rope lights to illuminate a wooden walkway (a catwalk with railings, actually).  I've put a string alongside each edge (at the bottom).  Midway along the catwalk, there is single step about 6" high.  I want to illuminate it for safety, and I'm not sure how best to do it.

1. I've zip-tied the rope light along the front edge of the step's nosing.  I've got it very straight and tight against the nose, and it looks good.  I'm afraid, however, that footfalls, rolling over the front edge of the nose, will loosen it so it becomes a trip hazard and/or the lights are damaged.
2. Route a groove a little ways back from the edge, that the rope lights will fit snugly into - maybe cement it with RTV silicone. I think it'll be good for people stepping up, but I'm not so sure about stepping down.
3. Put it along the bottom of the riser (in the corner between the lower-level of the walkway and the step).   I'm thinking this could be best.  I think it'll provide great illumination for stepping up, and should also provide a good visual cue for stepping down, although it doesn't explicitly mark the nose.   It shouldn't present any trip hazard either.

Maybe I just need to experiment.  But I'd welcome insight or other ideas.

[image]

Comment: Lighting below eye level should be directed downward. There's a reason we don't have eyebrows on the bottom of our faces. It should be under the nosing. Show us the situation so we can better assess. I'd consider extending your nosing to a more standard size anyway. Also: [Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#/media/File:SiliconCroda.jpg) | [Silicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone#/media/File:Caulking.jpg)

Comment: Have you considered installing a ramp instead?  A single step in a long walkway seems like something that could easily be replaced with a ramp.  (Hard to say how well this would work in your case without pictures though.)  Not only would the trip hazard be completely eliminated, but it makes it friendlier to people who might be physically impaired.

Comment: If you're just running rope lights, run the rope across the bottom of the tread nosing (assuming your have a nose, not just squared off). 
 Screw some clamps into the riser to keep the rope in place.  Something like this, depending on the diameter of your rope: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-3-8-in-1-Hole-Plastic-Cable-Clamps-15-Pack-PPC-1538/100167050

Comment: The photograph seems to show a post on the left side at the top of the step. Perhaps you could install a _courtesy light_ in or on that post to illuminate the step. A different color, e.g. red, would help call attention to the area. Adding one on the far face of the post angled toward the step would highlight the riser. There are a variety of weather resistant devices [here](https://www.superbrightleds.com/vehicle-lights/led-accent-lighting/led-courtesy-lights-for-boats) just to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fix it to the underside of the step nose so that it illuminates the riser and the deck below the step.

You could possibly drill through the nose and install light pipes (pieces of PMMA, or other clear, solid rod) to let some light out the top so that climbers know where to aim and descenders know where to get off.

Comment: Unfortunately the step nose doesn't stick out from the riser (more than maybe 1/4").  I guess I could put in a new tread piece with a more normal nose.  Failing that, just a little below the top of the nose, so footfalls don't disturb it ?

Comment: Anyhow, I feel that both your answer and #3 in the OP will do well for a person stepping upwards.   But I'm un-convinced either will work well for the person stepping downward - since there's no lighting on the very verge of the step.

Comment: yeah. perhaps route a vee groove and install the strip pointing down at an angle.

Comment: I added light pipes to indicate the edge.

Comment: V-groove in the front edge of the nose ?   Maybe a piece of plexiglass with the rope light inside it, somehow affixed to the front edge ?

Comment: "Light pipes" ?   Have a pic ?

Comment: Lighting is often and typically installed under the nosing. This provides very adequate illumination of the entire tread below, including accenting the edge. There's no need to overthink this.

Answer (score 12):

An example of under-the-nose lighting. This was installed shortly after a friend broke her foot in someone else's garage when she missed a single step between bays.

Garage steps:
[image: Garage Steps]

Bottom view:
[image: Bottom View]

Bottom view of both steps in the dark:
[image: Bottom View Of Both Steps In The Dark]

View from doorway:
[image: View From Doorway]

View from standing in garage:
[image]

Apologies for the quick and dirty snapshots.  And yes, those are blue LED strips.

Answer (score 5):

If you simply run it along the edge of the walkway, the step is obvious from the sudden vertical section in the edge of the walkway lighting.

Depending on details we can't see because you haven't posted pictures, you might also divert upwards along whatever railing structure edges the catwalk at that point for more emphasis that "something is different here" and more light in just that area.

Comment: Added a picture.

Comment: I might add some distinctive extra lamps at the point of the step.   This tells the user that "something's different here" and minimise the chance of forgetting the step from either direction.   Maybe a decorative fixture, maybe use some different colour, perhaps even an arch over this spot with a single god-light straight down at the step so it looks like a street light with a pool of light under it.

Comment: Come to think of it, those floodlights (in the picture) are positioned to aim at the step.  Duh.